# Copy files from one directory to another using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, generics, office365, excel-2010

**First question:**

I have a Excel File with a column like this :
[File Excel Invoice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHpP8.jpg)

What I need is :

[Option Selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpOdn.jpg)

**Second question**

Do I need different Sub's for each option ?

**Here my code**

```
  Option Explicit

Public CarpetaSeleccionada As String

Sub CopiarArchivosFacturas()

UserForm1.Show vbModal
If CarpetaSeleccionada = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must select a source folder.", vbCritical, "Error"
    Exit Sub
End If

    ' 1. Open an Excel file determined by the user
    Dim archivo As Variant
    archivo = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel File's (.xls;.xlsx), .xls;.xlsx")

    If TypeName(archivo) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub 'If the user cancels the selection

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(archivo)

    ' 2. Search for the word "invoices" in the Excel sheet
    Dim hoja As Worksheet
    Set hoja = wb.Sheets(1)

    Dim palabra As String
    palabra = "Invoice Number"

    ' 3. Locate and indicate in which column and row the word "invoices" is located
    Dim rangoBusqueda As Range
    Set rangoBusqueda = hoja.UsedRange

    Dim celda As Range
    Set celda = rangoBusqueda.Find(palabra)

    Dim FIL As Long
    Dim COL As Long
    FIL = celda.Row
    COL = celda.Column

    ' 4. Display the form for the user to select the source folder
    UserForm1.Show
    If CarpetaSeleccionada = "" Then
        MsgBox "You must select a source folder.", vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' 5. Build source path based on user selection
    Dim rutaOrigen As String
    rutaOrigen = "C:\" & CarpetaSeleccionada & "\"

    ' 6. Prompt user to select destination folder
    Dim rutaDestino As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "You must select a source folder"
        .InitialFileName = "C:"
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox "You must select a destination folder.", vbCritical, "Error"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            rutaDestino = .SelectedItems(1) & ""
        End If
    End With



     ' 7. Create  the object FileSystemObject
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


    
    
    ' 8. Copy all files found under the invoices cell that match the files in both folders and subfolders in the source directory
    Dim archivoFactura As Range
    Dim i As Long

    For i = FIL + 1 To hoja.Cells(hoja.Rows.Count, COL).End(xlUp).Row
        Set archivoFactura = hoja.Cells(i, COL)
        Dim nombreArchivoFactura As String
        nombreArchivoFactura = archivoFactura.Value

        CopiarArchivoRecursivo rutaOrigen, rutaDestino, nombreArchivoFactura, fso
    Next i


    ' 9. Close the Excel file
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    '10.-
    MsgBox "Ended process", vbInformation, "Operación completada"
End Sub


Sub CopiarArchivoRecursivo(ByVal rutaOrigen As String, ByVal rutaDestino As String, ByVal nombreArchivoFactura As String, ByRef fso As Object)
    Dim archivoEncontrado As Object
    Dim archivoCopiado As Boolean
    archivoCopiado = False

    ' Find and copy files that match the invoice name
    For Each archivoEncontrado In fso.GetFolder(rutaOrigen).Files
        If InStr(1, archivoEncontrado.Name, nombreArchivoFactura, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Dim newFileName As String
            newFileName = archivoEncontrado.Name
            Dim counter As Integer
            counter = 1
            While fso.FileExists(rutaDestino & newFileName)
                newFileName = fso.GetBaseName(archivoEncontrado.Name) & "(" & counter & ")." & fso.GetExtensionName(archivoEncontrado.Name)
                counter = counter + 1
            Wend
            fso.CopyFile archivoEncontrado.Path, rutaDestino & newFileName, True
            archivoCopiado = True
        End If
    Next archivoEncontrado

    ' If file is not found in source folder, search subfolders recursively
    If Not archivoCopiado Then
        Dim carpeta As Object
        For Each carpeta In fso.GetFolder(rutaOrigen).SubFolders
            CopiarArchivoRecursivo carpeta.Path, rutaDestino, nombreArchivoFactura, fso
        Next carpeta
    End If
End Sub
```

I have tried to make the options form but it gives me an error and the program is blocked .

> GRAPHIC EXPLANATION OF THE OBJECTIVE CODE

[GRAPHIC EXPLANATION OF THE OBJECTIVE CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2GQ9.jpg)

Comment: Needs more description of the *specific* problem you're having with getting this code working.

Comment: I have added an explanatory graphic where the purpose of the code is explained.

Comment: Have you tried running the code under the debugger attached?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev yes, I have checked with the debugger, but it doesnt give me any information about what's the error....